# MATLAB search row index of matrix with values of another matrix

Tags: matlab, search, indexing, row

In MATLAB I have a very large matrix (matrix A). Now I would like to find the row-index of the row which contain certain values in the **second** column. These values - which I'm looking for in Matrix A - are stored in anonther Matrix (Matrix B) with consists out of a row (800 numbers).

Besides I would like to redo this calculation for the same matrix A, but for ten different matrices, with different sizes (which contain the values I'm looking for in **different** columns of matrix A).

Because of the sizes of the matrix I think i need a loop to extract the row in matrix A which contain te value of Matrix B. How can I do this?

regards,

V

Thanks for the quick response! Indeed the problem is maybe a bit complex to answer without an example, and indeed duplicate entries cause some problems. Therefore hereby an example

For example I have a -simplified- matrix A:

1  2  3 4

9 9  9  9

4  3  2 1

And a -simplified- matrix (row) B: [9  3]

And a -simplified- matrix (row) C: [9  2]

Then I would like to get matrix D and matrix E.These matrices should contain in the first column the numbers from the original matrix D(or E) and in the second column the corresponding row-location of this value in matrix A.

So, matrix D =

9  2

3  3

matrix E =

9  2

2  3

As represented in this example matrix B and matrix C can contain data which is present in several column of matrix A (like the nine). However, martix B should "search" in column 2 of matrix A. Likewise, should matrix C "search" in column 3 of Matrix A, resulting in matrix D and E as given in the example.

Comment: your description is **extemely** complicated. Can you give **short** code snippets that can help us understand what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Oke, I updated the discribtion. Hopefully it is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by Shai in his comment, your question is quite vague and a lot of special case could arise (duplicate entries, relative size of A and B, etc.). But in all generality I tried a small piece of code that seems to do what you want. There are certainly quicker ways of doing it, and certainly more information on your problem could help optimize this.

```
colA=2;
% Example
nmax=10;
nA=5;
A=randi(nmax,[nA nA]);
nB=3;
B=randi(nmax,[1 nB]);
% Find rows
rows=cell(size(B));
for i=1:numel(B)
    rows(i)={find(A(:,colA)==B(i))};
end
```

The input / output was:

```
A =
     3     7     8     5     4
     9     7     3     7     5
     8     2     9     9     8
     9     5     9     7     9
     3     3     4     6     8

B =
     1     7     5

rows =
     [0x1 double]    [1;2]    [4]
```

Comment: This seems very promising! By adding: D= cell2mat(rows)
Matrix=[B;D]' I get the solution I want. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two vectors, `largeDataIndex` (the second column of your matrix) and `interestingIndex` (your b) and you want the following:

```
For each value of interestingIndex , find the position in largeDataIndex
```

Then an easy method would be this:

```
result = zeros(size(interestingIndex))
for i = 1:length(result)
    result(i) = find(interestingIndex(i) == largeDataIndex)
end
```

Note that this assumes there is always just one entry that matches, otherwise you should define result as a cell array rather than a vector.